# How can I add styling to a dropdown hint in nativescript-angular?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm using nativescript with angular and I want to change the css to a dropdown hint to match other control placeholders on my application.

but I couldn't find a way yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like the following in your `js/ts` code

```
var element = document.getElementById("dropdown");
element.classList.add("myCssClass");
```

where you get the element you want and then append your `css` class, which you have to have defined already.

Comment: I'm using nativescript and ts dropdowns are in the form of :

    <DropDown [hint]="placeholder" class="dropdown"></DropDown>
so the text for the hint needs to have some styling